# powershell won't start without CD in drive

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7-x64, powershell-3.0

I am using Windows 7 and have upgraded to Windows Management Framework 3.0, which includes PowerShell 3. Within the past week or so, I have started getting an error upon starting PowerShell that prevents it from starting until there is a CD in my computer's drive (any CD will do). The only fix I have found so far—and this is only a temporary fix—is to completely uninstall and reinstall the Management Framework. This works until I use the CD drive for something, then PowerShell starts acting up again. The error dialog reads: `There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive D:.`

Does anybody have any suggestions for what might be going on here? I see two possible problems related to configuration settings, but still need guidance about what/where to check and verify:

- PowerShell is configured somewhere to check certain drives on startup, and isn't responding well to an empty CD drive
- PowerShell is actually trying to open to some path on `D:\`. I'm pretty sure this is *not* the problem, since it opens to my `%USERPROFILE%` when there *is* a CD in the drive, but of course I could be missing something
- Of course, I'm sure there are plenty of other possibilities I haven't considered

Any thoughts on possible fixes? I'd like not to have to uninstall and reinstall the Management Framework every time I use my CD drive!

**EDIT: Additional details below copied from my responses to various comments**

- I can recreate the error by launching PowerShell in multiple ways. Shortcut is one. Starting it from a Command Prompt (cmd.exe) is another. Even trying to call a PowerShell script from a Command Prompt using something like `PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File script.ps1` produces the error, and so does `PowerShell /?`.
- I don't see anything pointing to `D:\` in `$env:PATH` and `$env:HOMEDRIVE` is not set to `D:`. `%windir%` is set to `C:\Windows`, `%SystemDrive%` is set to `C:`, and `%SystemRoot%` is set to `C:\Windows`.
- Re-assigning the CD drive to a different letter resolves the problem, but this isn't a solution because it addresses the symptom and not the underlying cause (whatever *that* is).
- When everything else fails, I can still start PowerShell from Cygwin
- Process Monitor (linked below) is showing an attempt to read a non-existant registry entry `HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\MuiCache\5E6\52C64B7E\@D:\Windows\system32\AccessibilityCpl.dll,-10`. Whatever mechanism is causing that bad read is likely also causing the error dialog. **Something must be programmatically changing the system drive within PowerShell itself.**

Further thoughts and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: How do you start powershell?  From a shortcut?

Comment: Multiple ways. Shortcut is one. Starting it from a Command Prompt (cmd.exe) is another. Even trying to call a PowerShell script from a Command Prompt using something like `PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File script.ps1` produces the error.

Comment: Do you have a D: section in your PATH statement?

Comment: I'm guessing your `%HOMEDRIVE%` is set to your disk drive

Comment: In a cmd prompt - if you type `powershell /?` then it still occurs right?

Comment: I don't see anything pointing to D:\ in `$env:PATH` and `$env:HOMEDRIVE` is *not* set to `D:`. Yes `Powershell /?` causes the error.

Comment: Try `echo %path%` in the cmd prompt.  Are there any variables in the PATH statement, or `D:` ?  As a test, set your optical drive to drive `R:` and see what error message you get.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the question your asking, but any environment variables in `%PATH%` would be expanded when cmd.exe opens, right? If that's what you're referring to, then I don't see any variables, and every entry in `%PATH%` starts with `C:`. Also, I did assign the CD drive to a different letter and that resolved the problem. I wouldn't really call that a solution though, since it addresses the symptom and not the underlying cause.

Comment: Here is something really bizarre: even when everything else fails, I can still start PowerShell, but only from Cygwin.

Comment: Try using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from sysinternals and have it monitor powershell.exe to track down the problem.

Comment: Good thought. The Monitor is showing an attempt to read a registry entry `HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\MuiCache\5E6\52C64B7E\@D:\Windows\system32\AccessibilityCpl.dll,-10`. The problem is, of course, Windows isn't in the D: drive. The registry entry `HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\MuiCache\5E6\52C64B7E\@C:\Windows\system32\AccessibilityCpl.dll,-10` *does* exist. Before you ask, `%windir%` is set to `C:\Windows`, `%SystemDrive%` is set to `C:`, and `%SystemRoot%` is set to `C:\Windows`. Something must be changing it programmatically.

Comment: Check your profiles - 

notepad $profile.allusersallhosts
notepad $profile

Comment: No files exist where `$profile` is pointing, either for my user or allusersallhosts.

Answer (score 0):

When Powershell first launches, it checks designated folders to import modules.  I would take a good look at these.  The default var is $env:PSModulePath and acts much like the standard $env:Path var.  I would review that path and see if there are any references to the D: drive there.

[MSDN - Windows PowerShell Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878324(v=vs.85).aspx)

Are you installing .net from the DVD drive?  Maybe downloading a fresh copy from MS would clear this up.  MS .Net Framework 3.0 is very old, it is actualy designated for Server 2003 or WinXP.  Is there a reason you are using it instead of 3.5, 4 or 4.5.1?